# Is a lambda expression a delegate?

Tags: c#

I can't directly pass a lambda

```
form.Invoke(() => AMethod(form));
```

Because oddly enough a lambda is not a delegate type (per the compiler error). I seem to recall different information in Jon Skeet's .NET 4.0 book. And on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) it says:

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use **to**
>    **create delegates** or expression tree types

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();                                
        form.Show();
        form.Invoke(() => AMethod(form));
        Application.Run();

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AMethod(Form form)
    {
        form.SendToBack();
    }
}
```

Yet, here we receive a compiler error:

> *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it
>   is not a delegate type.*

Lambda's are supposed to be syntactic sugar for anonymous delegates. So what is the story here? What have I missed?

Comment: BTW, in addition to the answers below, feel free to create an extension method that takes an `Action` delegate type that in turn wraps the `Form.Invoke` method. That way you can have the nice syntax you have above without having to explicitly cast/construct an `Action` every time.

Comment: I believe there is a subtlety that I missed too.  There's a difference between a delegate keyword and a Delegate Type.

Comment: `delegate` keyword defines a new `MulticastDelegate` subclass type. So for example: `Action : MulticastDelegate : Delegate : Object`. `Delegate` uppercase exists as a type `System.Delegate`. Just to make things fun though, we often interchange `delegate` (keyword), `Delegate` (type), and "delegate" (concept) :) Though typically, if you see `Delegate` uppercase, it is in reference to the `System.Delegate` type but not always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, lambdas are used to create delegates, but they are not themselves delegates.  The primary issue here is that lambdas don't have a signature, their parameter list and return type are determined based on the context they are placed in.  When you place a lambda somewhere where a particular defined delegate instance is expected then the compiler knows what signature the lambda must match to be valid.

`Invoke` on the other hand doesn't take some particular delegate type, it takes an instance of `Delegate` which doesn't have any signature.  You need to wrap your lambda in `new SomeActualDelegateType(...)` (`Action` is a common choice for some delegate here, but not the only choice) to give it an actual signature.

Answer (score 6):

Lambda's themselves are not delegates. But, like your quoted text, they can be used to create delegates:

```
form.Invoke(new Action(() => AMethod(form)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create Action: `form.Invoke(new Action(() => MyMethod(form)));`